How do I use validation to prevent a user from duplicating Datagrid value?
I am trying to figure out how to prevent users from adding or renaming fields in a datagrid, if the value they choose is a duplicate. For example, if there is a directory of Person objects, if someone tries to add a name that already exists, they get an error. Or if they edit an exiting value in the datagrid to a name that already exists, it throws an error and prevents them from doing it. It's simple to prevent this if the user programmatically tries to add a person with the same name to the directory, but I don't know how to check for this if the change occurs on the view (e.g. in the datagrid).
Person class:
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        public Person(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

Directory class:
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class Directory
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }

        public Directory()
        {
            People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        }

        public void RemovePerson(Person person)
        {
            if (People.Contains(person))
            {
                People.Remove(person);
            }
        }

        public void AddPerson(Person person)
        {
            if (NameExists(person))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot have duplicate names!");
                return;
            }  
            
            People.Add(person);
        }

        public bool NameExists(Person person)
        {
            return People.Any(p => p.Name == person.Name);
        }
    }
}

MainWindow.xaml.cs:
namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Directory Directory { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Directory = new Directory();
            Person p1 = new Person("Bob");
            Person p2 = new Person("John");
            Person p3 = new Person("Al");
            Directory.AddPerson(p1);
            Directory.AddPerson(p2);
            Directory.AddPerson(p3);

            dgDirectory.ItemsSource = Directory.People;
        }
    }
}

MainWindow.xaml:
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgDirectory" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>


Do you use a database?

No. The example above is just a simplified version of my issue, but otherwise nothing different. Just trying to figure out how to validate changes to the the People list when those changes come from the view, like when the user changes the name from the datagrid.

I will provide an example later.

You should implement INotifyDataErrorInfo.
If you would only use row validation then you could use the built-in row validation feature of the DataGrid (which is basically concerned with providing the visual error feedback). However, it doesn't behave properly when used together with cell validation where the validation is performed using INotifyDataErrorInfo instead of binding validation. This is because of the special way the DataGrid handles columns and column bindings.
This example therefore chooses to implement custom validation error feedback via simple style triggers.
I would consider this a two-level validation: 1) the row item itself, that implements INotifyDataErrorInfo to validate each property for the correct input (e.g. format, length etc.) where the context is the item itself. And 2) the owner of the source collection that performs the item validation in context of all items (e.g. duplicates, total number of entries etc). In general, 2) is about validating the row item against the external context (the context that is hidden from the row item).
So, the first step is to let Person implement INotifyDataErrorInfo.
The key is to use the built-in feature of the DataGrid to handle IEditableObject implementation. This way you can wait for the user to finish editing the row without requiring UI related events. When the editing is completed, we can notify the owner that manages the Person source collection about the changes, so that the owner can perform addition validation that involves the owner's context. In your example, you want to ensure uniqueness of a data set (table row).
In table data structures there are two types of uniqueness: 1) row and 2) column. For example, "Name = John; Lastname = Doe" and "Name = John; Lastname = Wick" are usually not considered equal data sets (rows), although the column "Name" contains a duplicate. Uniqueness 1) is checked using simple object equality whereas uniqueness case 2) requires an advanced implementation of the rules that define uniqueness.
For this reason, Person must extend its behavior so that it defines and evaluates instance uniqueness by comparison.

Implement IEquatable and override the object.Equals methods to define object equality (row uniqueness).
Implement IEditableObject to enable edit state tracking. The Person will then raise a Person.Edited event that we introduce for this purpose.
Implement INotifyDataErrorInfo to enable property validation.
Implement a custom Person container that enables the owner to conveniently observe the Person.Edited event without having to register a handler for each item.
Implement the visual error feedback for the DataGrid using simple style triggers and templates to layout the error visuals.

Person.cs
public class Person : IEditableObject, INotifyDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged, IEquatable<Person>
{
  // Nested type which is used as data store for the Person 
  // to enable simple data editing and roll-back
  private class PersonData
  {
    public PersonData()
    {
    }

    // Copy constructor
    public PersonData(PersonData personData)
    {
      Name = personData.Name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  public string Name
  {
    get => _personData.Name;
    set
    {
      _personData.Name = value;

      // Example property validation to provide cell erors
      Validate(
        value, 
        val => val is not null && val.Contains("@") ? (false, new[] { "Contains 1" }) : (true, Enumerable.Empty<string>()));
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  // We introduce this collection for binding the error template so that it 
  // can show all current error messages without accessing 
  // the _errorMessages Dictionary
  public List<string>? InstanceErrors 
    => _errorMessages?.Values.SelectMany(message => message).ToList();

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
  private PersonData _backupData;
  private PersonData _personData;
  private const string InstanceErrorsIdentifier = "";

  public Person(string name)
  {
    _personData = new PersonData();
    _errorMessages = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    Name = name;
  }

  public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

  #region IEditable implementation

  public bool IsEditing { get; private set; }
  public event EventHandler<EditedEventArgs> Edited;

  void IEditableObject.BeginEdit()
    => CreateBackup();

  void IEditableObject.CancelEdit()
    => RestoreFromBackup();

  void IEditableObject.EndEdit()
    => CommitEdit();

  private void CreateBackup()
  {
    _backupData = new PersonData(_personData);
    IsEditing = true;
  }

  private void RestoreFromBackup()
  {
    _personData = _backupData;
    IsEditing = false;
  }

  private void CommitEdit()
  {
    IsEditing = false;
    OnEdited();
  }

  private void OnEdited()
  {
    ClearErrors(InstanceErrorsIdentifier);

    var eventArgs = new EditedEventArgs(this);
    Edited?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
    if (!eventArgs.IsValid)
    {
      AddErrors(InstanceErrorsIdentifier, eventArgs.ErrorMessages);
    }
  }

  #endregion IEditable implementation

  #region Implementation of INotifyDataErrorInfo

  // Call this method from the properties to validate their value
  private void Validate<TValue>(
    TValue value, 
    Func<TValue, (bool IsValid, IEnumerable<string> ErrorMessages)> validationDelegate, 
    [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName);

    ClearErrors(propertyName);

    (bool isValid, IEnumerable<string> ErrorMessages) result = validationDelegate.Invoke(value);
    if (!result.isValid)
    {
      AddErrors(propertyName, result.ErrorMessages);
    }
  }

  private void AddErrors(string propertyName, IEnumerable<string> errorMessages)
  {
    _errorMessages.Add(propertyName, errorMessages.ToList());
    OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
  }

  private void ClearErrors(string propertyName)
  {
    _errorMessages.Remove(propertyName);
    OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
  }

  public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs>? ErrorsChanged;

  private void OnErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HasErrors));
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InstanceErrors));
    ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  private readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> _errorMessages;

  public bool HasErrors => _errorMessages.Any();

  public IEnumerable GetErrors(string? propertyName)
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
    {
      return _errorMessages.Values.SelectMany(message => message).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
      return _errorMessages.TryGetValue(propertyName, out List<string> errors)
        ? errors
        : Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
  }

  #endregion Implementation of INotifyDataErrorInfo

  #region Implementation of IEquatable

  public bool Equals(Person? other) => other.Name.Equals(Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  #endregion Implementation of IEquatable

  public override bool Equals(object? obj) => obj is Person other ? Equals(other) : false;
  public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(this.Name);
  public override string? ToString() => Name;
}

EditedEventArgs.cs
public class EditedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public EditedEventArgs(Person person)
  {
    Person = person;
    _errorMessages = new List<string>();
    ErrorMessages = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(_errorMessages);
  }

  public void SetErrors(IEnumerable<string> errors) => _errorMessages.AddRange(errors);

  public Person Person { get; }
  public ReadOnlyCollection<string> ErrorMessages { get; }
  public bool IsValid => !_errorMessages.Any();
  private readonly List<string> _errorMessages;
}

PersonCollection.cs
[DebuggerDisplay("Count = {Count}")]
[Serializable]
public class PersonCollection : ObservableCollection<Person>
{
  #region Overrides of ObservableCollection<TItem>

  /// <inheritdoc />
  protected override void InsertItem(int index, Person item)
  {
    base.InsertItem(index, item);
    StartListenToItemPropertyChanged(item);
  }

  /// <inheritdoc />
  protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
  {
    if (index < this.Count)
    {
      Person item = this.Items[index];
      StopListenToItemPropertyChanged(item);
    }

    base.RemoveItem(index);
  }

  /// <inheritdoc />
  protected override void ClearItems()
  {
    foreach (Person item in this.Items)
    {
      StopListenToItemPropertyChanged(item);
    }

    base.ClearItems();
  }

  /// <inheritdoc />
  protected override void SetItem(int index, Person item)
  {
    if (index < this.Count)
    {
      Person oldItem = this.Items[index];
      StopListenToItemPropertyChanged(oldItem);
      StartListenToItemPropertyChanged(item);
    }

    base.SetItem(index, item);
  }

  #endregion Overrides of ObservableCollection<TItem>

  private void StartListenToItemPropertyChanged(Person item)
    => WeakEventManager<Person, EditedEventArgs>.AddHandler(item, nameof(Person.Edited), OnPersonChanged);

  private void StopListenToItemPropertyChanged(Person item)
    => WeakEventManager<Person, EditedEventArgs>.RemoveHandler(item, nameof(Person.Edited), OnPersonChanged);

  public event EventHandler<EditedEventArgs> PersonChanged;

  private void OnPersonChanged(object item, EditedEventArgs e)
    => this.PersonChanged?.Invoke(item, e);
}

Directory.cs
public class Directory
{
  public PersonCollection People { get; }

  private readonly EqualityComparer<Person> _personComparer;

  public Directory()
  {
    People = new PersonCollection();
    People.PersonChanged += OnPersonChanged;

    // We use the uniqueness that Person defines
    _personComparer = EqualityComparer<Person>.Create((person1, person2) => person1.Equals(person2), null);
  }

  private void OnPersonChanged(object? sender, EditedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (People.Contains(e.Person, _personComparer))
    {
      // Invalidate the Person to report a row error 
      // and provide error messages
      e.SetErrors(new[] { "Person already exists1" });
    }
  }

  public void RemovePerson(Person person)
  {
    if (People.Contains(person))
    {
      People.Remove(person);
    }
  }

  public void AddPerson(Person person)
  {
    if (NameExists(person))
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Cannot have duplicate names!");
      return;
    }

    People.Add(person);
  }

  public bool NameExists(Person person)
  {
    return People.Any(p => p.Name == person.Name);
  }
}

MainWindow.xaml
<UserControl x:Class="Net.Wpf.PrintableContentHost"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Net.Wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450"
             d:DesignWidth="800">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DefaultDataGridRowStyle"
           TargetType="DataGridRow"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Item.HasErrors, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Value="True">
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                  Value="Red" />
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                  Value="1" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DefaultOverrideRowValidationErrorTemplate" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultRowHeaderTemplate" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="RowHeaderValidationErrorTemplate"
                  DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
      <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="&#xEA3B;"
                   FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                   AutomationProperties.Name="Favorite"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="Red"
                   FontSize="14" />
        <TextBlock Text="&#xE783;"
                   FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                   AutomationProperties.Name="Favorite"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="White"
                   FontSize="16" />
        <Popup x:Name="NotificationPopup"
               AllowsTransparency="True"
               IsOpen="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=Item.HasErrors, Mode=OneWay}"
               StaysOpen="True"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRowHeader}}"
               Placement="Bottom">
          <Border Background="White"
                  BorderBrush="Red"
                  BorderThickness="1"
                  CornerRadius="4"
                  Padding="4">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=Item.InstanceErrors[0]}"
                       Background="White"
                       Foreground="Red" />
          </Border>
        </Popup>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="DefaultDataGridRowHeaderStyle"
           TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
              Value="{StaticResource DefaultRowHeaderTemplate}" />
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
              Value="Center" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasErrors, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Value="True">
          <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                  Value="{StaticResource RowHeaderValidationErrorTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
      <Setter Property="RowValidationErrorTemplate"
              Value="{DynamicResource DefaultOverrideRowValidationErrorTemplate}" />
      <Setter Property="RowStyle"
              Value="{StaticResource DefaultDataGridRowStyle}" />
      <Setter Property="RowHeaderStyle"
              Value="{StaticResource DefaultDataGridRowHeaderStyle}" />
    </Style>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  
  <!-- 
    We have to set the RowValidationErrorTemplate to an empty dummy value 
    to prevent the DataGrid from showing its default 
  -->
  <DataGrid RowValidationErrorTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultOverrideRowValidationErrorTemplate}"
            RowHeaderWidth="30"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding People}" />
</Window>

